# rake release hangs when releasing a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake, release

I'm trying to release my first gem to Ruby Gems. The gem is working great locally.

I'm releasing it using:

```
$rake release
```

Which gives me this in the console:

```
example_gem 0.0.3 built to pkg/example_gem-0.0.1.gem 
Tagged v0.0.1
Pushed git commits and tags
```

Then the process hangs. I waited 20 mins, then cancelled.

When I tried to release again I got:

```
rake aborted!
This tag has already been committed to the repo.
```

So I assumed the gem had been successfully submitted, however 16 hours later, the gem is not under my account on Ruby Gems.

So I bumped the version and tried again using `--trace`, but the process hangs in the same place with only the following additions to output:

```
** Invoke release (first_time)
** Execute release
example_gem 0.0.3 built to pkg/example_gem-0.0.3.gem
Tagged v0.0.3
Pushed git commits and tags
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of Google searches and archives: I encountered the same issue but for a different reason. When I used the recommended command to download my RubyGems credentials file:

```
curl -u pond https://rubygems.org/api/v1/api_key.yaml > ~/.gem/credentials; chmod 0600 ~/.gem/credentials
```

...I must have mis-typed my password, as the file actually contained the text "`HTTP Basic: Access denied.`". No error had been output to the console. Repeating the `curl` command and being more careful with password entry resulted in a sensible `credentials` file and the next attempt to run `rake release` worked.

If you get complaints about an existing tag you probably just need to delete it locally; use:

```
git tag
```

...to see what's there and once you've identified the version based tag (e.g. "v2.0.0") delete it with:

```
git tag -d <tag_name>
```

Comment: how to do this on window?..i tried this but its turn out "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: I can't help with Windows sorry, I don't use it. I generally find software development is only really viable on OS X or Linux hosts unless you're doing something 100% Microsoft-centric within their IDE.

Perhaps you're copying my command directly - `~/.gem/credentials` is a Unix-like pathname. The `~` means "your home folder". You'd need to put the equivalent Windows path in there... `C:\blah\blah\blah` or something more evolved; Windows is extremely strange.

Answer (score 0):

Bumped the version and tried again. This time it worked. Only change I made was to remove Gemfile.lock from git.