# system("git push 2>&1") works fine, but %x(git push 2>&1) hangs. Why?

Tags: ruby, git, shell, ssh

I am using Ruby. I am trying to figure out why bundler's `rake release` hangs on the `git push` step, as also [discussed inconclusively here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464710/rake-release-hangs-when-releasing-a-gem).

I've narrowed it down to this line of code hanging:

```
    `git push 2>&1`
```

I can reproduce the problem by running the same line of code in IRB.

What's mysterious is that the underlying `git push` does in fact execute, but for some reason Ruby never receives the return status. It just waits for the child process indefinitely.

Inspecting the process listing shows that the child process has `Z+` (zombie?) status:

```
    UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD   USER       PGID   SESS JOBC STAT   TT 
    501 23397  3757   0  1:44PM ttys001    0:00.54 irb   mbrictson 23397      0    1 S+   s001 
    501 26035 23397   0  2:06PM ttys001    0:00.00 (sh)  mbrictson 23397      0    1 Z+   s001
```

Obviously, `git push` runs just find in my shell. It's just when it is invoked via Ruby using backticks that it hangs.

Also, this works fine:

```
    system("git push 2>&1") # => true
```

And this (i.e. with out the output redirection) works fine too!

```
    `git push` # => "Everything up-to-date"
```

Part of the problem is apparently `ControlMaster auto` in my `~/.ssh/config`. When executing `git push`, this causes a new control connection process to be spawned in the background. Perhaps `%x(git push 2>&1)` is waiting for this background process to exit? If I disable ControlMaster in my SSH config, this does in fact solve the problem.

Still, this bothers me. I would rather not have to disable ControlMaster simply to make Ruby's backticks operator happy.

Can anyone explain:

- Why does `%x()` hang but `system()` does not?
- Why does removing `2>&1` make a difference?

This is on Mac OS X Yosemite with Ruby 2.2.0.

Comment: The `%x` version captures the output, the `system` version does not. I'm not sure if that affects `git`, where it might ask questions that hold up the process for some reason. If you want to know what's going on, it's best to use [`popen3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) for maximum control.

Comment: Does it matter whether git has anything to do when the command is run?

Comment: @EtanReisner it doesn't seem to have anything to do with what git is doing. I see the problem when there are commits to push, and when everything is up to date.

Comment: What do the fd's of the ssh processes look like when it is going to hang? The extra process is probably confusing the backticks when it comes to waiting on output (which as tadman indicated `system` doesn't wait for).

Comment: @tadman I don't think git is asking questions; like I said, removing `ControlMaster` seems to be the deciding factor. I'm hoping to figure out the underlying cause more out of curiosity than anything else. If it is a common problem, perhaps bundler will accept a PR to switch to popen3.

Comment: @EtanReisner My hunch is that the SSH control connection is maintaining a link to stderr of the parent process. Since stderr is being redirected to stdout and %x is waiting on the output, maybe that is why it is hanging. Any ideas on how I can test that hypothesis or force SSH's control connection from hanging onto stderr?

Comment: This seems to back up my hypothesis: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/openssh/dev/57396 . Unfortunately no answers there either.

Comment: If the control master connection is still running at the hang point then you can check the fd's via `/proc/<pid>/fds/`. Otherwise you can try running `ssh` directly (instead of via `git`) with a remote command of `sleep`/etc. so that you can inspect the state manually while both `ssh` processes are still running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out:

> Why does %x() hang but system() does not?

%x() waits to fully read the output of the child process; system() does not care about the output.

[According to this bug report](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1988), the `ControlPersist` setting in OpenSSH causes stderr to be left open for the lifetime of the master connection. In my SSH config, I have `ControlPersist 5m`, and sure enough, %x() hangs for exactly 5 minutes before finally completing.

This doesn't affect `system()` because system does not wait on the output.

> Why does removing 2>&1 make a difference?

As explained above, the SSH master connection leaves stderr open. It apparently closes stdout. Since stdout is closed, `%x(git push)` finishes immediately because there is nothing to wait for on stdout. When `2>&1` is added to the command, this causes stderr to be redirected to stdout. Since stderr is being left open by the master connection, this in turn causes stdout to remain open. `%x` waits on stdout and hangs.

Unfortunately this behavior of OpenSSH shows no sign of being changed, so there is no satisfying solution other than disabling `ControlPersist`.